# Best acronym/abbreviation for the word "template"

Tags: abbreviations, terminology, acronyms

What would be the proper way to shorten the word "template" down to maximum of 3 symbols for use in busy diagrams and schemes in (bio)chemical context?

From [here](http://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/template) and [there](https://www.allacronyms.com/template/abbreviated) I only found **TPL** and **TML** examples to be more or less suitable. Also, just **T** is often used in the specialized literature, but I find it rather improper as it could easily be confused with "temperature". So which one is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about proper SE section, please let me know if this question fits [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) better.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but I would say TPL is best because you are capturing significant parts of the word. **T**em**PL**ate. The T stands for the first syllable, and the PL for the second.

Comment: @Dangph Thank you, this was my feeling too, I just didn't know how to substantiate it. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: To reduce potential confusion to a nullity, I would use **TEMPLATE**; or are vowels verboten by convention? If so, I propose **TMPLT**.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I would prefer to keep the abbreviation as short as possible, but still recognizable and more or less unique. As I mentioned, this one goes into rather complex drawings where literally every letter counts, and using more than 3 symbols would be a luxury. Vowels are fine though.

Comment: If space is critical, you should dispense with abbreviations entirely and use a key. A small graphic in a lower corner (commonly called a _legend_ in English) informs the reader of the equivalencies, e.g: _**T = Template**_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant As I mentioned, **T** is reserved pretty much *by design* as "temperature" across many branches of natural science. Reassigning this one may cause a lot of confusion, as the same abbreviation goes into the text.

Comment: Then use teeny weeny pictures. Invent your own local morphology. I see this all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just my opinion, but I would say **TPL** is best because you are capturing significant parts of the word: **T**em**PL**ate. The **T** stands for the first syllable, and the **PL** for the second.